# Copying local SSH key to remote host if it doesn't exist already

Tags: ssh, bash

There are plenty of tutorials out there for a straightforward SSH key copy, but none that would check if the key doesn't already exists remotely. This should work:

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh -p <port> <user>@<hostname> 'sh -c "if ( ! grep -q '`cat -`' ~/.ssh/authorized_keys); then cat - >>~/.ssh/authorized_keys; fi"'
```

The `cat -` inside the grep doesn't get interpolated into a single string but 3, and that throws the whole thing off. I did it in Ruby and it works, but it's not ideal. Any bash pro around?

```
  Net::SSH.start(<host>, <username>, :password => <password>, :port => <port>) do |ssh|
    local_public_key = `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`.chomp
    ssh.exec! %{
      if ( ! grep -q '#{local_public_key}' ~/.ssh/authorized_keys ); then echo '#{local_public_key}' >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys; fi
    }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just use a variable, like this:

```
KEY=$(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub) ssh -p <port> <user>@<hostname> "if [ -z \"\$(grep \"$KEY\" ~/.ssh/authorized_keys )\" ]; then echo $KEY >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys; echo key added.; fi;"
```

Comment: Excellent! Now I just need to figure the command-line expect to pass the password and I'm done.

Comment: `grep` exit status indicates if it matched, so simpler `"if ! grep -q \"$KEY\" file; then echo $KEY >>file; echo added; fi"` or even `"grep -q \"$KEY\" file || (echo $KEY >>file; echo added)"`

Answer (score 4):

Why not just use [ssh-copy-id](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ssh-copy-id)?

> NAME
>
> ```
>  ssh-copy-id -- copy public   keys to a remote host
> ```
>
> SYNOPSIS
>
> ```
>  ssh-copy-id [-lv] [-i keyfile] [-o   option] [-p port] [user@]hostname
> ```
>
> DESCRIPTION
>
> ```
>  The ssh-copy-id utility copies public keys   to a remote host's
>  ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file (creating the file and   directory, if
>  required).
>
>  The following options are available:
>
>  -i   file
>    Copy the public key contained in file.  This option can be speci-
>    fied multiple times and can be combined with the -l option.  If a
>    private key is specified and a public key is found then the pub-
>    lic key will be used.
>
>  -l        Copy the keys currently held by ssh-agent(1).  This is the
>    default if the -i option was not specified.
>
>  -o   ssh-option
>    Pass this option directly to ssh(1).  This option can be speci-
>    fied multiple times.
>
>  -p   port
>    Connect to the specified port on the remote host instead of the
>    default.
>
>  -v        Pass -v to ssh(1).
>
>  The remaining arguments are a list   of remote hosts to connect to, each
>  one optionally qualified by a user   name.
> ```
>
> EXIT STATUS
>
> ```
>  The ssh-copy-id utility exits 0 on   success, and >0 if an error occurs.
> ```
>
> EXAMPLES
>
> ```
>  To   send a specific key to multiple hosts:
>  $ ssh-copy-id -i /path/to/keyfile.pub user@host1 user@host2
>  user@host3
> ```

Comment: Because ssh-copy-id does not test and always adds even if the key is already there, which is exactly what the Q does not want.

Comment: From [https://www.ssh.com/ssh/copy-id](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/copy-id):

`It also checks if the key already exists on the server. Unless the -f option is given, each key is only added to the authorized keys file once.`

Comment: not on the system I checked -- but I didn't notice that was a several-years-old version. On checking OpenSSH source I see it was upgraded starting with 6.2 in 2013 to check for already existing and with 7.2 in 2016 to override with -f. And my (newish) FreeBSD version also checks, but differently! For an arbitrary system of unspecified heritage, I'd call it uncertain.

Answer (score 3):

Old question maybe, but you can also execute:

```
ssh -q -o "BatchMode=yes" user@hostname exit
```

Which if ssh-copy-id already happend will succeed and return 0. If not return an error.